# :name_prefix is not effecting anything on namespace routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying for a day to solve this one...

Moving an app from rails 2 to rails 3, I've encountered some problems with the Routes.

I want to use the :name_prefix option on the 'namespace' method. Can I do that?

I've tried getting the same results with the 'scope' option but still got to a dead end.

Here is a sample code and the routes it produces:

```
namespace :blog, :name_prefix => 'admin_' do
  resources :contexts   
end

scope :module => 'blog', :path_name_prefix => 'admin_' do
  resources :contexts   
end
```

rake routes:

```
blog_contexts GET    /blog/contexts(.:format) blog/contexts#index {:name_prefix=>"admin_"}
              POST   /blog/contexts(.:format) blog/contexts#create {:name_prefix=>"admin_"} new_blog_context GET    /blog/contexts/new(.:format) blog/contexts#new {:name_prefix=>"admin_"} edit_blog_context GET    /blog/contexts/:id/edit(.:format) blog/contexts#edit {:name_prefix=>"admin_"}

blog_context GET    /blog/contexts/:id(.:format) blog/contexts#show {:name_prefix=>"admin_"}
             PUT    /blog/contexts/:id(.:format) blog/contexts#update {:name_prefix=>"admin_"}
             DELETE /blog/contexts/:id(.:format) blog/contexts#destroy {:name_prefix=>"admin_"}


contexts GET    /contexts(.:format) blog/contexts#index {:path_name_prefix=>"admin_"}   

       POST   /contexts(.:format) blog/contexts#create {:path_name_prefix=>"admin_"} new_context GET   

/contexts/new(.:format) blog/contexts#new {:path_name_prefix=>"admin_"} edit_context GET    /contexts/:id/edit(.:format) blog/contexts#edit {:path_name_prefix=>"admin_"} context GET    /contexts/:id(.:format) blog/contexts#show {:path_name_prefix=>"admin_"}
        PUT    /contexts/:id(.:format) blog/contexts#update {:path_name_prefix=>"admin_"}
        DELETE /contexts/:id(.:format) blog/contexts#destroy {:path_name_prefix=>"admin_"}
```

It's hard to notice the difference but the namespace method adds its name to (1) the path-name, (2) the path itself - what you see in the browser, and (3) as the controller prefix.

The scope method only adds a controller prefix.

As you can see, the :name_prefix is not effecting anything in the path name - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand you correctly, but you probably want to do something like this:

```
scope :admin do
  scope :blog do
    resources :contexts
  end
end
```

And an option B (but not as nice) would be:

```
scope :blog, :as => 'admin_blog'
  resources :contexts
end
```

Comment: Indeed, :name_prefix seems to be deprecated.